# Почему Phpspreadsheet создает поврежденный файл?

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

Установил на сервер библиотеку Phpspreadsheet.
Использую тестовый код из документации:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello World !');

$writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
$writer->save('report.xlsx');
```

После запуска скрипта файл на сервере создается, но при открытии в MS Office (Libre Office) получаю сообщение о том, что фал поврежден. Попытка восстановления не удается. Файл невозможно открыть.
При этом формат CSV работает без проблем.
Библиотеку устанавливал через Composer. Ошибок при установке не было. Версия библиотеки -- 1.14. Версия PHP -- 7.3, все необходимые расширения установлены.

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобной проблемой?

Comment: Обычно файл xlsx можно таки открыть в блокноте или редакторе кода. Внутри чаще всего ошибка php и в какой она строке кода. Бывали косяки из-за путаницы с кодировками, например.

Comment: Если открыть файл в текстовом редакторе, отображается какой-то "бинарный" код вида: "504b 0304 1400 0000 0800 588a 0e51 4792"

Comment: Пардон, не подумал. Суть в том, что xlsx - это по сути zip-архив. Попробуйте распаковать.

Comment: Та же проблема: пишет, что архив поврежден.

Answer (score 0):

Ничего не обещаю, но попробуйте почистить/отключить буфер вывода перед сохранением.

```
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;

// Логика создания Вашей таблицы

ob_end_clean();
$writer = IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');
$writer->save(__DIR__ . '/report.xlsx');
exit();
```

Другие решения https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/issues/217#issuecomment-422810148

Comment: Для сохранения в файл это не существенно. Но я все равно пробовал этот вариант, для достоверности. И другие варианты тоже. Не помогает.